# Windows Phone LocalDB Method has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: linq, parsing, datetime, windows-phone, localdb

I want compare datetime (i need parse it) with now in LINQ query

```
From i In db.Downloads 
Where i.WantExpiration And DateTime.Parse(i.Expiration) < DateTime.Now
```

Everytime i get error: Method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

How i can in LINQ to SQL parse datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
From i In db.Downloads 
Where i.WantExpiration And i.Expiration < DateTime.Now
```

**provided that** Expiration is a DateTime column in your DB.

The error you are getting is expected since LINQ-SQL translates our linq queries in sql and then send them in the db, where there are executed and the results travel back to us. That being said, there isn't something similar like `DateTime.Parse()` in sql, so this method cannot be converted to a corresponding one in SQL. Hence your query cannot be translated in SQL.

If Expiration isn't a DateTime column in your DB, then you could make the following trick
(I see that you query is written in VB, but since I don't use VB, I will write my own in C# and subsequently, you could change it to VB.)

```
// Initially you will get all your data in memory.
var query = (from d in db.Downloads
            select d).AsEnumerable();

// Then you will query the in memory data.
var data = (from q in query 
            where q.WantExpiration && 
                  DateTime.Parse(q.Expiration) < DateTime.Now);
```